# Add or Remove HTML elements into view using data model in angular 2 with type script without using innerHTML and standard structural directive

Tags: html, angular, typescript, gwt, smartgwt

In smartGWT, there are various widget classes, which can be extended and create the required layouts. At runtime, these layouts will be added to html.  Now, I want to perform similar operations using Angular 2 with TypeScript i.e. write a code in a class such that it will add html forms and other elements to the view at runtime.

Below is the code.

This code provides a select element (select1).

**Requirement**

When user selects an option, another select item (select2) should be added to view and the options of select 2 should be the properties of the item selected in select1. When the selection changes in select1, the options of select 2 should be changed.

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';    
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, NgbModule.forRoot(), FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RelatedLinkImpl } from './RelatedLinkImpl';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/relatedLink.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent  { 

    relatedLinkList : Array<RelatedLinkImpl> = [new RelatedLinkImpl('Object0', 'Object0.object', ["a0","b0","c0"]), new RelatedLinkImpl('Object1', 'Object1.object', ["a1","b1","c1"]), new RelatedLinkImpl('Object2', 'Object2.object', ["a2","b2","c2"])];
    selectedLinkItem : RelatedLinkImpl;

    onConceptSelection() : void { 
        if (this.selectedLinkItem != null) {
            console.log("Link Text : " + this.selectedLinkItem.linkText + " Link Type : " + this.selectedLinkItem.linkType + " Link Properties : " + this.selectedLinkItem.linkProperties);
        }       
    }
 }
```

**RelatedLinkImpl.ts**

```
    export class RelatedLinkImpl {
  private _linkText : string;
  private _linkType : string;
  private _linkProperties : Array<string> = new Array<string>();

  constructor(linkText : string , linkType : string, linkProperties : string[]) {

    this._linkText = linkText;
    this._linkType = linkType;
    for(var i=0; i<linkProperties.length; i++) {
        this._linkProperties.push(linkProperties[i]);
    }
  }

  get linkText() : string {
    return this._linkText;
  }

  set linkText(linkText : string) {
    this._linkText = linkText;
  } 

  get linkType() : string {
    return this._linkType;
  }

  set linkType(linkType : string) {
    this._linkType = linkType;
  }

  get linkProperties() : string[] {
    return this._linkProperties;
  }

  set linkProperties(linkProperties : string[]) {

    for(var i=0; i<linkProperties.length; i++) {
        this._linkProperties.push(linkProperties[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

**relatedLink.component.html**

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="ruleStarting" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="selectedLinkItem" (change)="onConceptSelection()">
            <option *ngFor="let relatedLinkItems of relatedLinkList" [ngValue]="relatedLinkItems">{{relatedLinkItems.linkText}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Edit 1 :

Have refered following sources :

[Different form controls in Angular 2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2)

[Build Nested model driven forms in Angular 2](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2)

Edit 2 :

The question is how to add html elements at run time using angular 2 with typescript. The way we do it with smartGWT/GWT. Just right typescript classes in Angular 2 and generate the HTML applications.

Comment: "Below is my current working code"... So, if it works, what's the question?

Comment: The code is for the just a single select item, and code prints the responding values on the console.

Comment: Again, what's the question? Do you just want us to write the code for you so that the second select item works? Because that's not what Stack Overflow is about. Why don't you try and figure it out, then post the code you're having a problem with...

Comment: Nope. The question is  how to add html elements to the view template  from the component class or how to add html elements to the template view . That's why I have given example of smartgwt.

Comment: So, someone has to know smartGWT to understand the question? You should [edit] your question to explain exactly what you are not understanding. Please read [ask] for more information.

Comment: Beyond the "it should work like it does in SmartGWT", this has nothing to do with GWT or SmartGWT, imho.